# SFML compilation libGLEW

Tags: c++, compilation, sfml, glew

I have a compilation problem with the SFML : I don't have the good version of libGLEW (I have 1.6 version, the latest is 1.9, needed by SFML is 1.7) but I can't find it with aptitude.

```
 aptitude search glew
```

shows me the 1.5 or 1.6 versions...

Can you tell me how to quickly upgrade the library? Is that possible to manualy install this library ? (and explain me how, if possible !)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled manually the library :

1. Go to http://glew.sourceforge.net/
2. Select 1.7.0
3. Go to ~/Downloads/
4. tar -xvf glew-1.7.0/
5. cd glew-1.7.0
6. make
7. sudo cp /lib/* /usr/lib/

And it's ok !